# an exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_242-release) (JDK 11 installed)

Tags: java, flutter, flutter-dependencies

When i run my app, i have this error :

```
an exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_242-release). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.
java.lang.AssertionError: annotationType(): unrecognized Attribute name MODULE (class com.sun.tools.javac.util.UnsharedNameTable$NameImpl)
```

I have installed JAVA 11 and set all parameters in android studio for use JAVA 11 but...
The error indicates it uses bad version of java.
And when i do a flutter doctor -v i see it :

Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

How can i change it to JAVA 11 ? I have changed all in android studio in project structure - SDK - 11

Comment: Have you set JAVA_HOME and JDK_HOME in enviroment variables?

Comment: no. Where i need to set it ?

Comment: please refer to this article https://medium.com/@ruqaiyasattar/windows-development-environment-setup-for-flutter-application-8c7cdb1e5107

Comment: i have change JAVA_HOME and CLASS_PATH. I need to see if it changes something. But in JAVA_HOME the url was not JAVA 11 but the 1.8.0_251

Comment: So have your issue been resolved? You can check your java version from command prompt. java -version

Comment: when i do flutter doctor -v it says Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01) so it seems it doesn't work. and java--version i have java 11.0.21 2023-10-17 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.21+9-LTS-193)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.21+9-LTS-193, mixed mode)

Comment: Same problem : An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_242-release). i don't understand :(